# Does answering your own question constitute abuse on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, answers

This is my answer to multi-postings of the same or mostly same question. https://askubuntu.com/a/235007/46312 <--since deleted as not to offend

Are we allowed to ask-answer our own questions and therefor gaining reps and proliferating our own projects?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it's not considered abuse. You're encouraged to post useful content on the site:

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/
- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

> To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.

Though you should have probably just posted your issue on meta instead of as an answer to one of his posts to keep the site clean.

Answer (score 6):

Useful and distinct questions & answers are always positively encouraged.

In terms of your question I'm assuming you are concentrating on the *distinct* aspect of a Q&A.

In this case, the community has decided that this is a close enough duplicate and has been closed.

As such, the brief content that was posted as an answer was merged with the existing accepted duplicate.  I took the decision to not merge the answer since the OP had already had a similar answer on that duplicate.

The question itself is still very useful since it is a signpost for others searching using terms similar to the question title.

The beauty of the StackExchange system is that when searched, the user is automatically redirected.  So we have a win-win here.